# rewriting url works offline but not online

Tags: php

I'd like to remove .php extension from my urls. The problem is that some of my folders share the same name with some of my pages. For example I have a folder called "materiel" and a page called "materiel.php". I found the solution with this code:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Manually re-route materiel/ requests to materiel 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} materiel/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1

# Hide extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It works fine on my local version of the site, but not online (it leads to an error page). I already tried to add Options -MultiViews and DirectorySlash Off in my code without success. My host is 1&1. Maybe someone already experienced such a problem?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server ?

Comment: What does the error page say?

Comment: I think that mod_rewrite is enabled because the rewriting is working for all the pages which don't share the same name with a folder. The error page is just the 404.php I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Manually re-route materiel/ requests to materiel 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} materiel/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1

# Hide extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Try to set RewriteBase to your base directory.

Comment: Thanks for showing me what to work on. Since I created a folder in my server root, I had to write RewriteBase //. Now all is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

To exclude directories from being rewritten you can add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

as one of your rewrite conditions.